# Compute attribute value based on index within dom-repeat

Tags: polymer, polymer-3.x

I'm just getting started with Polymer and faced with the following issue.
I'm trying to pass a boolean value to pill component as an attribute.
Value of this attribute depends on dom-repeat's index.
How to do that in Polymer ?

This code is not working:

```
 <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[values]]">
   <pill
     disable="[[index === 0]]"
     part="pill">
     [[item]]
   </pill>
 </template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymer only allows for simple property bindings within attributes. Anything more complex than that needs to use a [computed binding](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#binding-annotation) which passes arguments to a functions. In your case it could be something along the lines of `disable="checkIndex(index)"` a function which would then check if the index is 0.

Another solution if you are only checking for 0, would be to use the [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) property of javascript: `disable="{{!index}}"` which would also disable the pill.